# NO_PUBKEY error for apt-get update behind proxy

Tags: apt, 15.04, proxy

At work I have an ubuntu desktop behind a proxy. I configured my proxy as follows: Under Settings > Network > Network proxy : Method set to "automatic", set a URL and applied system wide.

This enabled access to the internet (eg firefox), except for apt-get. To get apt-get working, I followed [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto) instructions, specifically under "Setting up apt-get to use a http-proxy > APT configuration file method".
With these settings I can install packages (eg thunderbird), but I have a problem when I add a new repository:

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 737F9811F93FF666
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with the proxy, but I can't seem to fix it with any method/tip I have found online so far. For example, adding the proxy settings as environment variables (`export https_proxy=...`) and then using `sudo -E` did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo -i
export http_proxy=http://foo.bar.com:1234 # change this to the correct values
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 737F9811F93FF666
exit
```

Hope that works for you.  If it doesn't then maybe post the error you get

Comment: It worked, thanks :) but does this mean I will have to explicitly import every key for a new repo like that? Or is there a global configuration change I can make to solve this problem once and for all?

Comment: you can use apt-add-repository to automate getting the key for PPAs.